# How to ignore .latexmkrc

Tags: latexmk

I usually love my .latexmkrc settings. However I am trying to play with `Template Toolkit` to build a LaTeX file, then compile it with `latexmk` (all of this inside a perl script) and thus I would like to use the default latexmk settings (i.e. no preview continuously etc).

I would like to keep my .latexmkrc for personal use, therefore I am looking for a way to tell `latexmk` to ignore my `$HOME/.latexmkrc` file (via the -r flag?). Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A belated answer: A new version of latexmk does what was asked for.  This is v. 4.27a at

http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/versions.html

Just invoke latexmk with the option -norc, and it will omit reading all its standard initialization files (system, user, and current directory).  The -r option still works, so you use a customized initialization file.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible using the `-r <rcfile>` option, because it doesn't override the loading of `$HOME/.latexmkrc` but this file is loaded in addition. Multiple `-r` options can be given and all of these config files are loaded in the given order.

One possibility to stop latexmk in your perl script to read `$HOME/.latexmkrc` is to temporary change the `HOME` variable and to change the current directory away from `$HOME` (because latexmk also looks for a `.latexmkrc` in the current directory.

Something like:

`# Perl code:

  $ENV{HOME} = '/dev/null';

  chdir('/tmp');

  system("latexmk ...");`

If you need the correct `HOME` anywhere else after this lines simply save it away and restore it afterwards.

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks. I really should have thought about that; got too focused on latexmk flags to think outside the box.

Comment: Now that I am on that track, a further idea would be to localize $ENV{'HOME'} to a block before calling latexmk. Then the home variable will be restored afterwards automatically. `...;{ local $ENV{'HOME'}; system( 'latexmk', '-pdf', $filename ); } ...`

Comment: @Joel: I know that. I just wanted to keep the Perl code minimal.

Comment: No slight intended. Call it a post for the future reader.

Comment: @Joel: No problem, wasn't meant like that.